# What word do the Rohingya people use to refer to the Rakhine State?

Tags: borders, minorities, myanmar

Minorities often have place-names for their ancestral/home lands that may differ from those provided by the language of the majority population. For instance, Scottish Gaelic would refer to Scotland as 'Alba'.

In reference to Rakhine State in Myanmar, the easily accessible media seem to offer no alternative names for it (e.g. [its wiki entry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rakhine_State)).

Hence, I was wondering what the Rohingyas themselves call Rakhine State, or do they call it the same? Or do they have a name for their homeland that does not geographically coincide with the borders of Rakhine State per se?